# How to cycle through divs using left/right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d34pksmn/1/

HTML:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%; position: relative; height: 165px; background: #00AC00;">
  <div class="dvSli" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 4;">
  </div>
  <div style="overflow: visible; position: absolute; left: 2%; top: 75px; z-index: 10; padding: 10px;">
    <span id="arrow-left"></span>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow: visible; position: absolute; right: 0; top: 75px; z-index: 10;">
  <span id="arrow-right"></span>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow: hidden; height: 40px; width: 100%; text-align: center;">
    A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
    <!-- Generate a letter for each occurance in `dCon` class DIV -->
  </div>
  <div class="dCon" style="overflow: auto; width: 6000000%; height: 125px;">
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 115px; height: 125px; background: #FF0000; position: relative; z-index: 3;">
  ONE
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 115px; height: 125px; background: #FF0000; position: relative; z-index: 3;">
  TWO
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 115px; height: 125px; background: #FF0000; position: relative; z-index: 3;">
  THREE
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 115px; height: 125px; background: #FF0000; position: relative; z-index: 3;">
  FOUR
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 115px; height: 125px; background: #FF0000; position: relative; z-index: 3;">
  FIVE
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 115px; height: 125px; background: #FF0000; position: relative; z-index: 3;">
  SIX
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 115px; height: 125px; background: #FF0000; position: relative; z-index: 3;">
  SEVEN
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 115px; height: 125px; background: #FF0000; position: relative; z-index: 3;">
  EIGHT
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 115px; height: 125px; background: #FF0000; position: relative; z-index: 3;">
  NINE
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 115px; height: 125px; background: #FF0000; position: relative; z-index: 3;">
  TEN
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I modify my HTML/CSS/JQuery so:

- Clicking on left/right arrow will slide each DIV inside the `dCon`
  class parent div, left if left is clicked and right if right is
  clicked.

I wanted to achieve the image carousel without the use of any plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain what you're asking for in part 2, can you be a bit more specific?

For the first part, here's an easy solution:

```
$(function() {
    $("#arrow-left").click(function() {
    $(".dCon div:first-child").appendTo(".dCon");
    $(".dCon").remove(".dCon div:first-child");
  });
  $("#arrow-right").click(function() {
    $(".dCon div:last-child").prependTo(".dCon");
    $(".dCon").remove(".dCon div:last-child");
  });
});
```

and the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JSnoobDC16/d34pksmn/6/

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. The only issue is, the spacing between each is disappearing?

Comment: Maybe you can help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748960/how-to-make-a-certain-div-first-child-and-anything-before-it-append-to-the-end Thanks.