# How to make a certain DIV first child and anything before it append to the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xkdm52gs/3/

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
var vhtml = "";
var u5 = new Array();
var $divs = $(".cHold");
var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find("span").text() > $(b).find("span").text();
        });
$(".dCon").html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
    $("#arrow-left").click(function() {
    //alert("left");
    $(".dCon div:first-child").appendTo(".dCon");
    $(".dCon").remove(".dCon div:first-child");
  });
  $("#arrow-right").click(function() {
    //alert("right");
    $(".dCon div:last-child").prependTo(".dCon");
    $(".dCon").remove(".dCon div:last-child");
  });

  $(".cHold").each(function() {
    var k = $(this).text().trim();
    console.log(k.charAt(0));
    u5.push(k.charAt(0));
  });
  console.log(unique(u5).length);
  u5 = unique(u5).sort();
  for (var k = 0; k < u5.length; k++) {
    vhtml += "<a class='aLink' href='javascript:void(0);'>" + u5[k] + "</a>";
  }
  $(".theLetNum").html(vhtml);
});

function unique(list) {
    var result = [];
    $.each(list, function(i, e) {
        if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
    });
    return result;
}
```

The left/right arrow is working fine but how can I also modify the script so when a letter is clicked the first instance of the DIV which represents the letter is the first child and if it wasn't the first child anything before it should append to the end.

So e.g. in the fiddle: If I click `N`, div with the text `Nine` should be the first child and div(s) with the text `Eleven`, `Five`, `Four` should append to the end in their respective order and so forth.

Comment: Method `element.prev()` returns all siblings before the element. If you then `append()` them into their `parent`, they will move to its end.

Answer (score 2):

1. have a look at jQuery prepend.
2. i think you would be better off using scrolling (overflow-x: scroll) for your selector, that will eliminate the need to reorder your dom.
3. flexbox is also a better solution for dynamic reordering

Comment: I would really like to use `2` but wasn't sure how I would implement it. As far as `3` goes, I was trying to avoid using a plugin (although yes it does make life easier)

Comment: for 2 you can just dedicate a container to your scrolling content and set it to overflow: scroll-x, then use jQ.scrollIntoView(); to scroll to a certain element.

Answer (score 1):

Attach this event on the letters. See the emaple by running it.

```
$(document).on('click', '.aLink', function() {
    var char = $(this).text();
    $elem = $('span').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().charAt(0) == char;
    }).parent().remove();
    $('.dCon').prepend($elem);
})
```

```js
$(function() {
  var vhtml = "";
  var u5 = new Array();
  var $divs = $(".cHold");
  var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).find("span").text() > $(b).find("span").text();
  });
  $(".dCon").html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
  $("#arrow-left").click(function() {
    //alert("left");
    $(".dCon div:first-child").appendTo(".dCon");
    $(".dCon").remove(".dCon div:first-child");
  });
  $("#arrow-right").click(function() {
    //alert("right");
    $(".dCon div:last-child").prependTo(".dCon");
    $(".dCon").remove(".dCon div:last-child");
  });

  $(".cHold").each(function() {
    var k = $(this).text().trim();
    console.log(k.charAt(0));
    u5.push(k.charAt(0));
  });
  console.log(unique(u5).length);
  u5 = unique(u5).sort();
  for (var k = 0; k < u5.length; k++) {
    vhtml += "<a class='aLink' href='javascript:void(0);'>" + u5[k] + "</a>";
  }
  $(".theLetNum").html(vhtml);
  $(document).on('click', '.aLink', function() {
    var char = $(this).text();
    $elem = $('span').filter(function() {
      return $(this).text().charAt(0) == char;
    }).parent().remove();
    $('.dCon').prepend($elem);
  })
});

function unique(list) {
  var result = [];
  $.each(list, function(i, e) {
    if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
  });
  return result;
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.dvSli {
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,ffffff+50,ffffff+100&1+0,0+25,0+50,0+75,1+100 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
#arrow-left {
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#arrow-left:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 45px;
  width: 15px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transform: skew(135deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(135deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(135deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(135deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(135deg, 0deg);
}
#arrow-left:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  right: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  width: 15px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-135deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-135deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-135deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-135deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(-135deg, 0deg);
}
#arrow-right {
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#arrow-right:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 45px;
  width: 15px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transform: skew(45deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(45deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(45deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(45deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(45deg, 0deg);
}
#arrow-right:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  right: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  width: 15px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-45deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-45deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(-45deg, 0deg);
}
.cHold {
  margin: 0 2px 0 2px;
}
.aLink {
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%; position: relative; height: 165px; background: #00AC00;">
  <div class="dvSli" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 4;">
  </div>
  <div style="overflow: visible; position: absolute; left: 2%; top: 75px; z-index: 10; padding: 10px;">
    <span id="arrow-left"></span>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow: visible; position: absolute; right: 0; top: 75px; z-index: 10;">
    <span id="arrow-right"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="theLetNum" style="overflow: hidden; height: 40px; width: 100%; text-align: center; position: relative; z-index: 5;">
  </div>
  <div class="dCon" style="overflow: auto; width: 6000000%; height: 125px;">
    <div class="cHold" style="display: inline-block; width: 115px; height: 125px; background: #FF0000; position: relative; z-index: 3;">
      <span>ONE</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cHold" style="display: inline-block; width: 115px; height: 125px; background: #FF0000; position: relative; z-index: 3;">
      <span>TWO</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cHold" style="display: inline-block; width: 115px; height: 125px; background: #FF0000; position: relative; z-index: 3;">
      <span>THREE</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cHold" style="display: inline-block; width: 115px; height: 125px; background: #FF0000; position: relative; z-index: 3;">
      <span>FOUR</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cHold" style="display: inline-block; width: 115px; height: 125px; background: #FF0000; position: relative; z-index: 3;">
      <span>FIVE</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cHold" style="display: inline-block; width: 115px; height: 125px; background: #FF0000; position: relative; z-index: 3;">
      <span>SIX</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cHold" style="display: inline-block; width: 115px; height: 125px; background: #FF0000; position: relative; z-index: 3;">
      <span>SEVEN</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cHold" style="display: inline-block; width: 115px; height: 125px; background: #FF0000; position: relative; z-index: 3;">
      <span>EIGHT</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cHold" style="display: inline-block; width: 115px; height: 125px; background: #FF0000; position: relative; z-index: 3;">
      <span>NINE</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cHold" style="display: inline-block; width: 115px; height: 125px; background: #FF0000; position: relative; z-index: 3;">
      <span>TEN</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you... It is appending to the beginning but if there are anything before it is not removed and appending to the back... Pretty I would like to keep the order the same :/ And I am clicking left/right it should continue from the position they are in now.

Comment: @Si8 great then you could $('.dCon .cHold:first-child').remove();
    $('.dCon').prepend($elem);

Comment: It might be one or multiple :/

Comment: START:
 `eight
 fourteen
 eleven
 four
 five
 nine
 one
 seven
 six
 ten
 thirteen
 three
 twelve
 two`

Clicking on N does this:

 `nine
 eight
 fourteen
 eleven
 four
 five
 one
 seven
 six
 ten
 thirteen
 three
 twelve
 two`

But I want it to do this:

 `nine
 one
 seven
 six
 ten
 thirteen
 three
 twelve
 two
 eight
 fourteen
 eleven
 four
 five`
 Let me know if that makes sense

Comment: @Si8 then might $('.dCon .cHold:lt('+$elem.length+')').remove()

Comment: I ended up using a scroller and this is what I have: https://jsfiddle.net/f1eb9fkz/. I just need help with PREV/NEXT and LETTER CLICK please.

Comment: The code is popping it and placing it in the front. I changed it up and instead using a scroller now.